# (Vue Apollo Client V4) gql template tag not running

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, apollo, apollo-client, vue-apollo

So we tried upgrading to **Vue 3** along with the **Vue Apollo client** (to V4). Everything seems to work fine such as apollo **within the script** so it's verified the library is running.

It's just that whenever we try to make use of  component within the template as instructed in: https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-components/query.html#query-gql-tag

No query is being executed. Trying to access v-slot="{result}" gives a null error.

Read the docs and nothing seems to be different in terms of setup. Has anyone else dealt with this?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use options-api version

https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-option/setup.html#_1-install-vue-apollo-option